# How can i count project status by change/update made

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I want to count status change by id from to

I have a mysql  status table which has a name with pre implementation, implementation and operations states.

- a project contains project id, name, start date fields.
- both status and projects have a many to many relationship called project_status table contains project_id, status_id, date_of_progress.

so i want to count all projects within this month who has update/change their status_id

1. from pre-implementation to implementations
2. from implementations to operations
3. from pre-implementation to operations

--

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_name_tg` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `status` (`status_id`, `status_name`, `description`, `status_name_tg`) VALUES
(1, 'Pre Implementation', 'Operational', 'Pre Implementation'),
(2, 'Implementation', NULL, 'Implementation'),
(3, 'Operational', NULL, 'Operational'),
(4, 'Inactive', NULL, 'Inactive'),
(5, 'Cancellation', NULL, 'Cancellation');

CREATE TABLE `project_status` (
  `project_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reason_for_cancellation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `project_status` (`project_status_id`, `status_id`, `time`, `project_id`, `reason_for_cancellation`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2019-02-24 21:51:50', 1, NULL),
(2, 2, '2019-03-26 21:52:57', 1, '        '),
(3, 1, '2019-04-30 21:57:57', 2, NULL),
(4, 1, '2019-05-26 22:04:08', 3, NULL),
(5, 3, '2019-08-24 22:06:36', 1, '        '),
(6, 2, '2019-08-11 22:07:05', 3, '        '),
(8, 1, '2019-08-01 00:14:41', 6, NULL),
(9, 1, '2019-08-09 12:11:22', 7, NULL),
(10, 1, '2019-08-09 12:15:22', 8, NULL),
(11, 3, '2019-08-14 10:07:49', 7, NULL),
(12, 2, '2019-08-14 10:10:45', 8, NULL),
(13, 2, '2019-08-26 17:16:02', 6, 'NULL');
(14, 3, '2019-08-26 17:16:02', 6, 'NULL');


CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `projects` (`project_id`, `name`, `start_date`) VALUES
(1, 'site A', '2019-02-01 00:00:00'),
(2, 'site B', '2019-03-12 00:00:00'),
(3, 'Site C', '2019-04-04 00:00:00'),
(4, 'Site D', '2019-05-03 00:00:00'),
(5, 'site E', '2019-06-01 00:00:00'),
(6, 'site F', '2019-08-02 00:00:00'),
(7, 'Site J', '2019-08-01 00:00:00'),
(8, 'Site H', '2019-08-05 00:00:00');
```

Desire Output

```
|pre - implementations|implementations - operations| pre - operations|
|2                    | 1                          |2                |
```

Comment: If this month a project moved from "pre" to "implementations" and then from "implementations" to "operations"... would you also count it as from "pre" to "operations"?

Comment: Can you skip one status step. Go from pre to operations? I guess you can go from pre to cancelation

Comment: @TheImpaler most cased this doesn't happen within this month but no i don't like to count it because its previous value is implementation(2) not the pre(1).

Comment: What is your MySQL version.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes it's possible if the project is failed or cancelled but the probability is less and if the query works for given scenario it may also work for it too

Comment: I also ask if is possible go from pre to operation. Seem unlike it

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza mysql version 5.7 and yes it's always possible to move a project from pre to operation. there are some cases this happen in my case

Comment: So if last month project was in pre, at begining of this month change to implementation and at the end of this month change to operations is count on both columns, isnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i want to count it as from implementation to operation not in both columns. regardless the i want to see its previous value for each current status changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is find what is the last status for each project on each month:

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e79087012794b4456a9fba085009d69&hide=3)**

```
SELECT YEAR(time) as year
     , MONTH(time) as month
     , project_id
     , MAX(status_id) as last_status
FROM project_status
WHERE status_id < 4   -- ignore (inactive, cancellation)
GROUP BY YEAR(time), MONTH(time), project_id;
```

OUTPUT

```
+------+-------+------------+-------------+
| year | month | project_id | last_status |
+------+-------+------------+-------------+
| 2019 |     2 |          1 |           1 |
| 2019 |     3 |          1 |           2 |
| 2019 |     4 |          2 |           1 |
| 2019 |     5 |          3 |           1 |
| 2019 |     8 |          1 |           3 |
| 2019 |     8 |          3 |           2 |
| 2019 |     8 |          6 |           2 |
| 2019 |     8 |          7 |           3 |
| 2019 |     8 |          8 |           2 |
+------+-------+------------+-------------+
```

Now using a correlated query you can found out the last status before the current month:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(p.status_id)
           FROM project_status p
           WHERE p.time < CONCAT(t.year,'/', t.month,'/1')
             AND p.project_id = t.project_id
           ) as previous_status
FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(time) as year
         , MONTH(time) as month
         , project_id
         , MAX(status_id) as last_status
    FROM project_status
    WHERE status_id < 4
    GROUP BY YEAR(time), MONTH(time), project_id
) t
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+------+-------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| year | month | project_id | last_status | previous_status |
+------+-------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 2019 |     2 |          1 |           1 |                 |
| 2019 |     3 |          1 |           2 |               1 |
| 2019 |     4 |          2 |           1 |                 |
| 2019 |     5 |          3 |           1 |                 |
| 2019 |     8 |          1 |           3 |               2 |
| 2019 |     8 |          3 |           2 |               1 |
| 2019 |     8 |          6 |           2 |                 |
| 2019 |     8 |          7 |           3 |                 |
| 2019 |     8 |          8 |           2 |                 |
+------+-------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Now just do some conditional counts

```
SELECT q.year
     , q.month
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN q.last_status = 2 THEN 1 END) as pre_implementation
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN q.last_status = 3 
                   AND q.previous_status = 2 THEN 1 END) as implementation_operation
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN q.last_status = 3 THEN 1 END) as pre_operation
FROM (
    SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(p.status_id)
               FROM project_status p
               WHERE p.time < CONCAT(t.year,'/', t.month,'/1')
                 AND p.project_id = t.project_id
               ) as previous_status
    FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(time) as year
             , MONTH(time) as month
             , project_id
             , MAX(status_id) as last_status
        FROM project_status
        WHERE status_id < 4
        GROUP BY YEAR(time), MONTH(time), project_id
    ) t
) q
GROUP BY q.year, q.month
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| year | month | pre_implementation | implementation_operation | pre_operation |
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| 2019 |     2 |                  0 |                        0 |             0 |
| 2019 |     3 |                  1 |                        0 |             0 |
| 2019 |     4 |                  0 |                        0 |             0 |
| 2019 |     5 |                  0 |                        0 |             0 |
| 2019 |     8 |                  3 |                        1 |             2 |
+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I think I have the right result but I  need you validate your data. In your desire output you said there are 2 from pre to implementation, but I can see there are 3.

Comment: It's urs & Works perfectly juan wasn't even run. Can i extended this query to join another table called categories through investment to project. Categories table has cat_id and name and investment has inv_id, cat_id and  project add one more filed inv_id to get categories by status. Each category as list and prep_imp, implementation_operation, pre_operation  as columns

Comment: Well you can do anything, but probably better if make a new question. Remember mark this answer if solve your question

Comment: i have asked a question per your request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800331/how-can-i-count-status-changed-updated-by-categories-for-a-specific-month the url

Comment: can you see my other question and give me the hint or result

Answer (score 0):

> so i want to count all projects within this month who has update/change their status_id

The following query gets you *all* the status changes:

```
select status_name, prev_status_name, count(*)
from (select ps.*, s.status_name,
             lag(s.status_name) over (partition by ps.project_id order by ps.time) as prev_status_name
      from project_status ps join
           status s
           on ps.status_id = s.status_id
     ) ps
where ps.time >= curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate())) day and
      status_name <> prev_status_name
group by status_name, prev_status_name;
```

You can further filter them if you want specific ones.

Note:  The results here are on separate rows rather than in separate columns.

You can get the results in separate columns using:

```
select sum( prev_status_name =  'Pre Implementation' and status_name = 'Implementation' ) as cnt1,
       . . .   -- for the remaining pairs that you want
from (select ps.*, s.status_name,
             lag(s.status_name) over (partition by ps.project_id order by ps.time) as prev_status_name
      from project_status ps join
           status s
           on ps.status_id = s.status_id
     ) ps
where ps.time >= curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate())) day and
      status_name <> prev_status_name;
```

The above works in the more recent versions of MySQL.  In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery or variables.  For instance:

```
select status_name, prev_status_name, count(*)
from (select ps.*, s.status_name,
             (select s2.status_name
              from project_status ps2 join
                   status s2
                   on ps2.status_id = s2.status_id
              where ps2.project_id = ps.project_id and
                    ps2.time < ps.time
              order by ps2.time desc
             ) as prev_status_name
      from project_status ps join
           status s
           on ps.status_id = s.status_id
      where ps.time >= curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate())) day and
     ) ps
where status_name <> prev_status_name
group by status_name, prev_status_name;
```

Comment: OP has mysql 5.7

Comment: @Gordon i have tested it on mariadb version 10.1.X not running the query can u give me online links i can test it

Comment: There is a sintaxis error I haven't found yet. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21dd4b06c449693c759e33e8cf98d132&hide=3  But I also think he didnt understand the whole question, because he work with day and prev day  instead of current month.