# how can i count status changed/updated by categories for a specific month

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

i want to count projects status updates/changes for a given month by categories names

I have a categories (list of category), investment (list of investors investments including category_id from categories), status table which has a name with pre implementation, implementation and operations states.
a project contains project id, name, start date fields.
both status and projects have a many to many relationship called project_status table contains project_id, status_id, date_of_progress.

I want to count all projects within this month who has update/change their status_id by categories names

from pre-implementation to implementations
from implementations to operations
from pre-implementation to operations

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `categories` (`cat_id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'agriculture', ''),
(2, 'manufactures ', ''),
(3, 'Technology', ''),
(4, 'services', '');



CREATE TABLE `investments` (
  `investment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `investment_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `investments` (`investment_id`, `investment_name`, `cat_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Company A', 3),
(2, 'Company B', 4),
(3, 'Company C', 1),
(4, 'Company D', 2),
(5, 'Company E', 3),
(6, 'Company F', 4),
(7, 'Company G', 1),
(8, 'Company H', 2);

CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_name_tg` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `status` (`status_id`, `status_name`, `description`, `status_name_tg`) VALUES
(1, 'Pre Implementation', 'Operational', 'Pre Implementation'),
(2, 'Implementation', NULL, 'Implementation'),
(3, 'Operational', NULL, 'Operational'),
(4, 'Inactive', NULL, 'Inactive'),
(5, 'Cancellation', NULL, 'Cancellation');

CREATE TABLE `project_status` (
  `project_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reason_for_cancellation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `project_status` (`project_status_id`, `status_id`, `time`, `project_id`, `reason_for_cancellation`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2019-02-24 21:51:50', 1, NULL),
(2, 2, '2019-03-26 21:52:57', 1, NULL),
(3, 1, '2019-04-30 21:57:57', 2, NULL),
(4, 1, '2019-05-26 22:04:08', 3, NULL),
(5, 3, '2019-08-24 22:06:36', 1, NULL),
(6, 2, '2019-08-11 22:07:05', 3, NULL),
(8, 1, '2019-08-01 00:14:41', 6, NULL),
(9, 1, '2019-08-09 12:11:22', 7, NULL),
(10, 1, '2019-08-09 12:15:22', 8, NULL),
(11, 3, '2019-08-14 10:07:49', 7, NULL),
(12, 2, '2019-08-14 10:10:45', 8, NULL),
(13, 2, '2019-08-26 17:16:02', 6, NULL),
(14, 3, '2019-08-26 17:16:02', 6, NULL);


CREATE TABLE `projects` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `investment_id` int(11) NOT NULL    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `projects` (`project_id`, `name`, `start_date`, `investment_id`) VALUES
(1, 'site A', '2019-02-01 00:00:00', 1),
(2, 'site B', '2019-03-12 00:00:00', 2),
(3, 'Site C', '2019-04-04 00:00:00', 3),
(4, 'Site D', '2019-05-03 00:00:00', 4),
(5, 'site E', '2019-06-01 00:00:00', 5),
(6, 'site F', '2019-08-02 00:00:00', 6),
(7, 'Site J', '2019-08-01 00:00:00', 7),
(8, 'Site H', '2019-08-05 00:00:00', 8);
```

Below is the result of Augus 2019

```
 +--------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
 | category_name| pre_implemntation | imp_operation | pre_operation |
 +------+-------+------------+-------------++-------------++--------+
 | agriculture  |     1             |          -    |           1   |
 | manufactures |     1             |          -    |           -   |
 | Technology   |     -             |          1    |           -   |
 | services     |     -             |          1    |           -   |
 +--------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: May you please explain only first row of the result. So that we can make the business rules from it?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai had a previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791052/how-can-i-count-project-status-by-change-update-made/57792706?noredirect=1#comment102024458_57792706) and i want to take that question further like group changes made with this month to categories names, on the previous question was grouped by year and month only. now i need the result of the above link result to distribute among the categories.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai can you give me some hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e46bc04f06597e72b78a35b9b383042&hide=3)**

```
SELECT q.year
     , q.month
     , q.name
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN q.last_status = 2 THEN 1 END) as pre_implementation
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN q.last_status = 3 
                   AND q.previous_status = 2 THEN 1 END) as implementation_operation
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN q.last_status = 3 
                   AND (q.previous_status = 1 or q.previous_status IS NULL)
                  THEN 1 END) as pre_operation
FROM (
    SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(p.status_id)
               FROM project_status p
               WHERE p.time < CONCAT(t.year,'/', t.month,'/1')
                 AND p.project_id = t.project_id
               ) as previous_status
    FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(time) as year
             , MONTH(time) as month
             , c.name
             , ps.project_id
             , MAX(status_id) as last_status
        FROM project_status ps
        JOIN projects p
          ON ps.project_id = p. project_id
        JOIN investments i 
          ON p.investment_id = i.investment_id
        JOIN categories c
          ON i.cat_id = c.cat_id
        GROUP BY YEAR(time), MONTH(time), c.name, ps.project_id
    ) t
) q
GROUP BY q.year, q.month, q.name
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+--------+-------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
|  year  | month |     name      | pre_implementation | implementation_operation | pre_operation |
+--------+-------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| 2019   |     2 | Technology    |                  0 |                        0 |             0 |
| 2019   |     3 | Technology    |                  1 |                        0 |             0 |
| 2019   |     4 | services      |                  0 |                        0 |             0 |
| 2019   |     5 | agriculture   |                  0 |                        0 |             0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
| 2019   |     8 | Technology    |                  0 |                        1 |             0 |
| 2019   |     8 | agriculture   |                  1 |                        0 |             1 |
| 2019   |     8 | services      |                  0 |                        0 |             1 |
| 2019   |     8 | manufactures  |                  1 |                        0 |             0 |
+--------+-------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Notice your month 8 services has only one record and is operation so go on the 3rd column and not on the 2nd as your desire result.

Comment: You can see the step by step on the sql demo. Also realize there was a mistake on the 3rd COUNT() didn't saw on the previous question and I fix here.

Comment: i also want to fetch for each project the most recent status

Comment: i did solve it (it's easy) and i have one more  question i need to see the all categories list names (i have few more categories) even they don't have any values for pre_implementation,implementation_operation, pre_operation with zero values but i don't see them on the month list.

Comment: You know the deal. Create a new question with proper data, so we know what you need. That way we don't waste time trying to guess.

Comment: i tried using left  join from the categories to investment but it didn't run for me

Comment: i've created a question like a duplication for this question